# null Pointer Exception At onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an activity which is having a Tablayout + Viewpager combination, together they are hosting four fragments out of which in one fragment I opening camera using Intent and parsing results there.

Sometimes when I am parsing results onActivityResults I am getting `NullPointerException`

Here is the code

```
public class CheckInFragment extends BaseFragment implements CheckInPresenterView {

    private CameraIntegrator cameraIntegrator;

    private ImageCallback cameraResultCallback = new ImageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(int requestedBy, Result result) {

            if (requestedBy == RequestSource.SOURCE_CAMERA) {
                ...
            }
        }
    };


    private void openCamera() {

        // Permission Check Shifted To Attendance Activity
        if (cameraIntegrator == null) {
            cameraIntegrator = new CameraIntegrator(this);
            cameraIntegrator.setImageDirectoryName(GlobalConstants.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
            cameraIntegrator.setRequiredImageSize(ImagesSizes.OPTIMUM_MEDIUM);
        }

        try {
            cameraIntegrator.initiateCapture();
        } catch (NoCameraAppFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CameraIntegrator.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                cameraIntegrator.parseResults(requestCode, resultCode, data, cameraResultCallback); //Null Pointer Exception here sometimes
        }
    }
}
```

Crashlytics Log :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.xxx.AttendanceActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.xxx.AttendanceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.xxx.CameraIntegrator.parseResults(int, int, android.content.Intent, com.xxx.camera.ImageCallback)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3513)
```

Can someone explain why I am getting cameraIntegrator  `null`  sometimes?

Is it because this code in parent activity?

```
    ViewPagerGeneralAdapter viewPagerAdapter = setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPagerAdapter.getCount()); <---
```

And How can I reproduce this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your `cameraIntegrator` in your fragments `onResume()` method instead. Problem is that if your fragment is recreated (for example, when returning from a different activity), your `openCamera()` method might not be called and thus, `cameraIntegrator` will  never have been initialised and will be null.

Try this.

```
@override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    initializeCameraIntegrator();
}


private void initializeCameraIntegrator(){
    if (cameraIntegrator == null) {
        cameraIntegrator = new CameraIntegrator(this);
        cameraIntegrator.setImageDirectoryName(GlobalConstants.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
        cameraIntegrator.setRequiredImageSize(ImagesSizes.OPTIMUM_MEDIUM);
    }
}

private void openCamera() {
    try {
        cameraIntegrator.initiateCapture();
    } catch (NoCameraAppFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joey I have doubts that this solution will work ,Here why (Correct me if I am wrong) whats happing now  -> fragment instance created say Fragment101 -> opencamera Button clicked in frag101-> camera Integrator created & it creates a file say image101.jpg -> camera Integrator passes the uri to file to native camera app -> photo clicked -> back to fragment -> fragment got recreated -> new fragment instance got created say Fragment102 -> onActivityResult() called on frag102 -> null pointer as cameraIntegrator is null for Fragment102

Comment: What You suggested -> fragment instance created say Fragment101 -> onResume() cameraIntegrator1 instance created -> opencamera Button clicked in frag101-> camera Integrator creates a file say image101.jpg -> camera Integrator passes the uri to file to native camera app -> photo clicked -> back to fragment -> fragment got recreated -> new fragment instance got created say Fragment102 ->onResume() cameraIntegrator2 instance created ->  onActivityResult() called on frag102 -> cameraIntegrator2 is not null but it's not refrencing to image image101.jpg

Comment: Okay. However the error you posted from crashlytics suggests that the `NullPointerException` occurs when calling `cameraIntegrator.parseResults(...)` so `cameraIntegrator` must be null somehow (this is kinda obvious since it says **null object reference**)

Comment: If your problem is that your initial `cameraIntegrator` creates `image101.jpg` as the uri passed via intent to the camera app, and a new instance would create a different reference, then I believe you should access the results from the camera app (where the final file is saved) in the `data` intent that's passed back in `onActivityResult` and hence handle it here (by using `data.getData()`)